# What does QNX's top CPU idle percentage really means?

Tags: cpu, top, qnx

I am using QNX (ARM Cortex A53 with FOUR cores) and when I do ***top***, I have the below.  According to the below idle percentages for each of the core, I'd like to confirm CPU/Core 0 is the most idle, that is, being used only ~7%, thus being the most candidate available for usage?  CPU 1 is maxed out with zero percentage of idling.

The one process uses most of one of the core is `my_app`, which has four thread.  Based idle CPU idle percentage info below, it looks like `my_app` is tied to Core 2.  But why is Core 1 has 0% of idling, that is, maxed out of percentage of usage.  Thanks for any explanation.

```
PID         TID PRI STATE    HH:MM:SS    CPU     COMMAND
1335344     9   254 Run      0:32:31     25.00%  my_app
1335344     5   253 Run      0:06:58     5.60%   my_app
1335344     7   253 Rdy      0:00:38     0.51%   my_app
1335344     6   253 Rdy      0:00:32     0.43%   my_app

              Min        Max       Average 
CPU 0 idle:   93%        93%        93% 
CPU 1 idle:    0%         0%         0% 
CPU 2 idle:   72%        73%        72% 
CPU 3 idle:   93%        94%        93%
 
Mem Avail:   1396MB      1396MB      1396MB  
Processes:    55         55         55    
Threads:     142        142        142
```

Comment: Why do you say "my_app is tied to Core 2"? Is the problem just a matter of "do we start numbering things from 0 or 1"?

Comment: It looks like `my_app` is tied to core 2, per my original post, because it looks like it uses around 30% of the CPU, and core 2 has around 72% left of idle.  Am I correct here?  Anyone?